# Include a third makefile with a path relative to second, when second isn't in directory of first

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile` with only project-level definitions: which source files to use, what binary or library to make, etc..

It includes `../../Make.Arch` for architecture-specific definitions (such as compiler command).

In turn, `Make.Arch` is meant to include `../etc/Makefile.Standard` for all the boilerplate of actually allowing the make system to work .

But `include` requires a path relative to where the makefile is actually being run (or maybe where the first Makefile is), not relative to the second... What to do?

Comment: Which makefile(s) are you allowed to modify?

Answer (score 1):

Make interprets relative paths from the working directory, the directory in which Make is being run. You haven't specified how you're running Make, so I'll assume your running it in the directory with `Makefile`.

If you are allowed to modify the makefiles, you can change the paths.

You could change `Make.Arch` from this:

```
include ../etc/Makefile.Standard
```

to this:

```
include ../../../etc/Makefile.Standard
```

but that would require that any makefile that uses `Make.Arch` be two directories down from it. That's clearly not a good idea. But we can use a variable:

```
include $(ARCH_DIR)/../etc/Makefile.Standard
```

which is provided by `Makefile` (or any other makefile that uses `Make.Arch`):

```
ARCH_DIR := ../..
include $(ARCH_DIR)/Make.Arch
```

If you are *not* allowed to modify the makefiles, then you must cheat. One way is to create a symbolic link to `Makefile.Standard`.

```
mkdir ../etc
ln -s ../../../etc/Makefile.Standard ../etc
```

Now `Makefile` will work. (It ought to be possible to make a link to `etc/`, but for some reason I can't get that to work right now.)